# Как лучше сделать вывод информации

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
#new {
  border: 4px double black;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 385px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#message {
  border: 4px double black;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 385px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="new">
 <img src="img/new.jpg" align="left" width="50" height="50">
 <font color="#000000" size="5">Свежие новости</font>
</div>
<div id="message">
 <img src="img/message.jpg" align="left" width="49" height="49">
 <font color="#000000" size="5">Новые сообщения</font>
</div>
```

Хочу выводить информацию под "Свежие новости" и "Новые сообщения".

Как это лучше всего сделать?

Если просто вставить текст в эти дивы, то вся картина искажается, и получается очень некрасиво. Мне бы не хотелось создавать еще 2 дива для этого дела. Как можно еще поступить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам такой вариант?

```
<div id="message">
    <div class="mtitle">Новые сообщения</div>
    <div class="mtext">Сообщение 1</div>
    <div class="mtext">Сообщение 2</div>
    <div class="mtext">Сообщение 3</div>
    <div class="mtext">Сообщение 4</div>
</div>

<style>
#message{
    border: 4px double black;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 385px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#message .mtitle{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 150%;
    padding: 0 10px 0 50px;
    background: url(img/message.jpg) left top no-repeat;
}
#message .mtext{
    font-size: 80%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Способ конечно хорош. Но возможны какие нибудь другие варианты(без использование дополнительных дивов)?

Comment: Вот скрин. Стрелками я отметил места где будут выводится сообщения-ссылки. http://s15.radikal.ru/i189/1104/67/53c38bd4f06b.jpg

Comment: Конечно. div.mtitle остается, остальные дивы удаляются. div#message прописывается расположение, обводка и стиль текста; div.mtitle переназначается стиль текста. Но новые сообщения, я так понимаю, у вас будут ссылками? Это тоже можно использовать.

Comment: Да. Новые сообщения будут ссылками. А как это можно использовать? И пожалуй задам еще один вопрос что-бы лишние темы не создавать. Как мне прижать футер к этому блоку? http://s44.radikal.ru/i104/1104/24/a930f015e1ad.jpg

Сейчас у меня такой футер :
#footer{
text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}

Comment: Использовать это можно так: заголовок растянуть на весь div, а сообщениям дать отступы.
Попробуйте потыкать в http://ling06.narod.ru/templatemaker/ - можно сделать по аналогии: без левого и правого меню и с вашими элементами в content'е. Если же надо прижать футер к низу страницы при любом контенте - Гугл в помощь).

Comment: В том то и дело что мне надо прижать футер не к низу страницы а к двум блокам. Как это можно сделать? Я пробовал но у меня не получилось к ним прижать.

Comment: <style>div{border:1px #000 solid}</style>
<div>header</div>
<div><div style="height:400px;display:inline-block">div1</div><div style="height:150px;display:inline-block">div2</div></div>
<div>footer</div>

Answer (score 2):

Да, либо вариант еще проще:

```
<div class="news">
    <h3>Свежие новости</h3>
    <div>Текст</div>
    <div>Текст</div>
    <div>Текст</div>
    <div>Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="messages">
    <h3>Сообщения</h3>
    <div>Текст</div>
    <div>Текст</div>
    <div>Текст</div>
    <div>Текст</div>
</div>
```

А вот этот вариант я бы сделал, если писал бы для себя:

```
<ul class="news">
    <li class="h">title</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Если сделать так то заголовок криво отображается. Возможно я что-то не так делаю...

Comment: У заголовков H1-6 есть отступы margin и padding, их нужно подправить. Вообще html - это такой специфический язык разметки, в котором из любого элемента можно сделать любой другой :)

Comment: Ну если написать стиль для заголовка, то для всех таких заголовков будет применен этот стиль. Или можно как то прописать стиль заголовка только для определенного дива?

Comment: Можно, конечно :) CSS - это КАСКАДНЫЕ таблицы стилей :) Пишите так: .news h3 - описывает заголовок только в элементе с классом news.

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще проще:
Для `font` сделайте `display:block` и тогда весь текст будет только под ним.
Сами блоки `#new` и `#message` сделайте `overflow:hidden`, тогда все будет внутри помещаться.

Но конечно жесткая высота блоков подразумевает, что ваш новый текст будет лимитирован по длине, кстати, в моем варианте все что не влезет, будет скрыто, очень удобно!